# Displaying data on next page with jQuery session or another possible way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

here my simple form:

```
<form id="myform">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email:<input type="text" name="email">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="click_btn">Submit</a>
</form>
```

I want to submit the form with Ajax, that bit is okay so far, and submitting.

Here is my jquery code:
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#click_btn').on('click', function() {

```
    $.ajax({
      url: $('myform').attr('action'),
      data: $('myform').serialize(),
      method: 'post',

      success: function(data) {
        //success meseg then redirct
        alert('success');

        var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();

        var dataObj = {};

        $(data).each(function(i, field) {

          dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
          window.location.href = 'next_page.php';
        });
      }

    })


  });
})
```

`next_page.php` is where I want to access, example:

```
<?php echo document.write(dataObj["email"]); ?>
```

I want to access these form values that I have submitted on next page after the form is submitted. I have created a data object with all the values using jQuery after submit, but still, I cannot access on the next page. Is there any concept related to the `session` in jquery for storing that array.

Comment: After making success in ajax call, you can redirect user to a new page passing the values in the address bar as params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting a couple of concepts confused here; I don't mean that in a condescending way, just trying to be helpful.

jQuery, and all JavaScript, exists only on the client-side (for practical purposes - there are exceptions where some client-side code might be rendered or compiled on the server-side for whatever reason but that's another matter). PHP, like any other server-side language, exists on the server-side. These two can't directly access each other's scope - which is why AJAX is useful to transfer data between the front and back ends.

Basically what you appear to be doing here is loading the data in the client-side, but not submitting anything to the server-side. You aren't actually doing any AJAX queries. When you redirect the user via `window.location.href =...`, no data is actually being transmitted - it simply instructs the browser to issue a new GET request to `next_page.php` (or wherever you instruct it to go).

There are a couple of options to do what you're trying to achieve:

1. Actually submit an AJAX query, using the methods outlined here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. You can then use `next_page.php` to grab the data and store it in a session and recall it when the user arrives on the page.
2. Store the data in a client-side cookie.
3. Use the standard HTML `<form method="next_page.php"...><input type="submit">` to cause the browser to forward the form data to the `next_page.php` script.
4. A number of other options but I think those are the simplest.

Comment: To clarify, loading data into `dataObj[field.name] = field.value;` in the client-side is only accessible on the client-side, whereas you are trying to recall `dataObj["email"]` on the server-side - unfortunately the data isn't magically transferred, so PHP has no knowledge of what JavaScript/jQuery was doing unless you explicitly tell it. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally use `sessionStorage` ! ([Here is documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage))

If user direct to next page in same tab, sessionStorage can easily save you data and reuse in next page.

```
// set in page A
window.sessionStorage.setItem('youdata', 'youdata');
// or window.sessionStorage['youdata'] = 'youdata';

// get in page B
var youdata = window.sessionStorage.getItem('youdata');
// or var youdata = window.sessionStorage['youdata'];
```

**That's it! very simple!**

If you'll open a new tab, you can use `localStorage`. ([Here is documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage))

The usage of `localStorage` is like the way of `sessionStorage`.

While do saving information for other pages, these two method only need browsers' support.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo document.write(dataObj["email"]); ?>
```

This is unreasoned! echo is a PHP command, but document.write is a JavaScript command.
If the secound page is PHP, why not send data with a simple POST submit from HTML Form?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use localStorage:

```
var data = '123';
localStorage['stuff'] = data;
```

Use `localStorage.clear();` to remove all data if you want to write it again or for specific item use `localStorage.removeItem('stuff');`

Answer (score 0):

List of some possible solutions are as follows:

**1. Post the data using AJAX request and the get it in next page by doing DB call (Advisable)**

**2. Using Local storage you can store the data in the browser to push it to  `next_page.php` https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp**

2a. In the first page

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("name", "John");
    localStorage.setItem("email", "John@test.com");
</script>
```

2b. In second Page

```
<script>
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var emaeil = localStorage.getItem("email");
</script>
```

**3. Using browser session storage https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp**

3a. In the first page

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", "John");
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", "John@test.com");
</script>
```

3b. In second Page

```
<script>
    var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
    var emaeil = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
</script>
```